# react-redux, sometimes working sometimes not when deleting from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I delete the order, sometimes the state is updated and sometimes not. It did not work 5 minutes and then started working correctly and I am wondering whether I've messed up something in my code.

action

```
export const deleteOrder = (token, id) => async dispatch => {

    const headers = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
    }

    const response = await api.delete(`/orders/detail/${id}`, headers)
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({ type: constants.PUSH_ERROR, payload: error })
        })

    if (response && (response.status === 204 || response.status === 301)) {
        dispatch({ type: constants.DELETE_ORDER, payload: id });
    }
};
```

reducer

```
case DELETE_ORDER:
            return {
                ...state,
                orders: state.orders.filter(o => o.id !== action.payload)
            }
```

You can ask for more code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a sandbox example.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)